# PHP inserting into MYSQL ' and " with sytax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

So, I am trying to insert into an mysql table a value of a variable. The variable contains both ' and " special characters, so when these occur, it gives a syntax error as it sees it as double ''. Any ideas how I can get around this? I have tried both '' and \" \" variations.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BBC (title, link, description, date)
    VALUES (\"$value\", \"$link1[$c]\", '$description1[$c]', \"$date[$c]\")";
```

Comment: Why not just escape your data if you're not already doing so, or use prepared statements.

Comment: Use a prepared statement and pass the variable values as parameters.

Comment: Do remember `date` is a reserve word. Though allowed but consider escaping it.

Comment: @Rahul date is not a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Yes it is but MySQL do allow then without escaping for kind a backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test this

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
    $link1[$c] = $mysqli->real_escape_string(link1[$c]);
    $description1[$c]= $mysqli->real_escape_string($description1[$c]);
    $date[$c]= $mysqli->real_escape_string($date[$c]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO BBC (title, link, description, date)
       VALUES 
      ('$value', '$link1[$c]', '$description1[$c]', '$date[$c]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use prepared queries with the parameters inserted by the db, but if you can't do that, you can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BBC (title, link, description, date)
VALUES ('$value', '$link1[$c]', '$description1[$c]', '$date[$c]')";
```